# edit and delete function for signed in users only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the current_user helper tag from rails in order to let users who are signed in EDIT and DELETE the objects they created whilst logged in.

This seemed to be working for me last week but now I have come back to my app and it has stopped. I also implemented the same function for my edit function on my show page  but it does not work. Please can someone tell me where I am going wrong do I have the right syntax for this function to work? Thank you in advance :)

My index.html.erb file:

```
 <div class="row justify-content-around p-3">
  <% @hairstyles.each do |hairstyle| %>
    <div class="card m-3">
      <div>
      <%= cl_image_tag hairstyle.photo, width: 300, height: 200, crop: :fill, class: 'card-image'%>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card2">
          <div class="card-body-inner1 transbox">
            <h5 class="card-title"><%= link_to hairstyle.name, hairstyle_path(hairstyle) %></h5>
            <p>Location: <%= hairstyle.location%></p>
          </div>

          <div class ="card-body-inner2 d-flex">
            <p> Likes</p>
            <p> Share</p>

          <% if hairstyle.user == current_user%>
           <p> <%= link_to "Delete", hairstyle_path(hairstyle), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%></p>
          <%end %>
          </div>         
      </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
def create
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.create(hairstyle_params)
    # @hairstyle.save ? (redirect_to hairstyle_path(@hairstyle)):(render 'new')
    @hairstyle.user = current_user
    if @hairstyle.save!
      redirect_to hairstyle_path(@hairstyle)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I think that you're using action_access, is a gem for rails. Well before you use that you should implement according to his documentation. https://github.com/matiasgagliano/action_access

Answer (score 1):

Can you specifiy what you mean by it stopped working please? Maybe you're not signed in currently?

Also for this functionality you should use an authorization tool like [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit). Because right now, you're just hiding the respective links to the actions in the view. But if the user would guess the url and type it in the browser, they could still delete or edit other users objects. Pundit, with it's concept of policies is avoiding exactly that.

Comment: Yes, when I created an account for a user then created a hairstyle the "delete" button showed up. However now when I log them out and then log back in with their account the delete button does not show up.. So strange. Ar yes I have heard of Pundit I will see how to implement it. Would you recommend that or action_access as others have mentioned above? thanks in advance

Comment: Well, the only explanation from your code above is, that the signed-in user (`current_user`) is not the `hairstyle.user`. Try to `raise` and check their IDs in the console. I assume you use devise for the sign in process?!
PS: Ahhh, you're Le Wagon alumni too? Let's connect on slack!

Regarding the gems, I have only worked with Pundit, but CanCan seems nice too. The action_access gem hasn't been maintained in 3 years (see the github), so I would not go for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Tip about your code, use cancancan gem to dry your code, also its help to centralise your "security access"

Answer (score 0):

According to your issue, I would recommend using action_access, is easy to implement, and easy to assign permissions to edit, delete or update for each user that you have.
Link: https://github.com/matiasgagliano/action_access

Comment: Ok great thanks for the recommendation I'll have a look now